# RingCentral API to download voicemail

Tags: api, ringcentral, voicemail

When someone leaves a voicemail, I would like to have RingCentral send an email to me with the voicemail attached as an audio file.   RingCentral sends a "notification" and optionally, the transcribed text of the voicemail, but not the audio file.  Can I use the RingCentral API to access the voicemail audio files (and transcriptions)?

Answer (score 1):

RingCentral already have the feature of sending notification mails with voicemail audio files.
You need to set the notification to your mail from your online account portal:

[image]

and you will get email that contains voicemail audio files:

[image]

If you want to get the audio file via API, you need to call the message store API:
GET [https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/%7E/extension/%7E/message-store)
and in response you will get the AudioTranscription and voice mail **media file url** something like this:

```
   {
....

    "attachments": [
    {
                
 "id": <id>,    
    "uri": 
https://media.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/<accountid>/extension/<extensionid>/message-store/<messagestireid>/content/<contentid>
    
    }
```

You can download the voicemail file from the attachment url